# localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 wamp server using OSPOS

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql

I'm using OSPOS open-source point of sale with wamp server but while I'm trying to access **reports> detailed reports>** I'm getting

```
Http request failed 500 internal server error
```

While I checked this error on internet I found may I've to install php5-gd library but in php5 it replaced with php-gd2 so this isn't case.

I'm using:

- OSPOS 3.0.2
- Wampserver 3.0.6
- Apache 2.4.23
- Mysql 5.7.14
- Php 5.6.25-7.0.10

PHP Error log :

```
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\application\models\reports\Specific_customer.php on line 67
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Stack trace:
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\public\index.php:0
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   2. require_once() C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\public\index.php:315
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   3. call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\vendor\codeigniter\framework\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:529}() C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\vendor\codeigniter\framework\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:529
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   4. Reports->specific_customer() C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\vendor\codeigniter\framework\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:529
[27-Feb-2017 21:06:26 Asia/Kolkata] PHP   5. Specific_customer->getData() C:\wamp\www\opensourcepos\application\controllers\Reports.php:728
```

I'm getting error only at ***detailed reports***

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Looks like a problem with OSPOS. Bug report time?

Comment: So I thought someone could help with it. Maybe who's familiar with PHP.

Comment: Looked over all the content and logic of all those files listed in the error error log and see if you can figure out what's going on to narrow it down a bit and then do some research there... I found this link of the OSPOS site: http://www.opensourceposguide.com/contact as well that you may be able to utilize. In order for someone to help unless they've had this issue before and confirmed it's the same issue and fix, you'd probably need to ensure people can see all the content of all those files to start looking over the logic, method calls, etc.

Comment: Wonder if `Specific_customer->getData()` could mean some report or data within being bad data or something in the definition, etc. or whatever it needs to be escaped or something confusing PHP when it executes... not sure though just a guess. I usually start with the top most error first anyway and that's the last in the set you provided.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, any luck ?

Comment: @naCheex I had [mail](http://www.opensourceposguide.com/contact) them issue but they don not reply back.

Comment: Issue resolved at my end, I have turned on socket module and its working fine

Comment: Can you explain it how? PHP socket module in WAMP server?